# Autoregressive model with observable noise

Tags: stochastic-processes, autoregressive, noise

The classical [autoregressive model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model) is a linear model for the dynamic variable $x$, where the added noise $\epsilon$ is directly affecting the dynamics of the model
$$x_{t} = \sum_i \alpha_i x_{t-i} + \epsilon_t$$
I am considering a related model, where the noise is only due to imperfect observation of the underlying variable, but does not directly affect the dynamics. Then, the dynamics of a hidden variable $x$ is given by

$$x_t = \sum_i \alpha_i x_{t-i}$$

and of the observable $y$

$$y_t = x_t + \nu_t$$

where $\nu_t$ is the observable noise.

**Questions**:

- Under what name is the "observable noise AR model"  known in the literature?
- Under what name is the composition of the above two models known in the literature? That is, a model that possesses both dynamic and observational noise

Comment: In your first equation, $\epsilon_i$ is supposed to be $\epsilon_t$

Comment: You seem to be looking for state space models.

Comment: @Firebug, it was a typo, thanks for spotting

Answer (score 2):

Consider the model
\begin{cases}
x_t = \sum_i \alpha_i x_{t-i}\\
y_t = x_t + \nu_t
\end{cases}

Substituting
$$y_t = \sum_i \alpha_i x_{t-i} + \nu_t\\
y_t = \sum_i \alpha_i (y_{t-i}-\nu_{t-i}) + \nu_t\\$$

This is an ARMA model in $y$ with a very specific constraint.

\begin{cases}
y_t = \sum_i \phi_i y_{t-i} + \sum_i \theta_i  \nu_{t-i} + \nu_t\\
\theta_i=-\phi_i
\end{cases}

Comment: Nice observation. What about the composite model? I have tried the same math as you did for composite model, and it looks almost like ARMA, but there are two sources of noise, one window-averaged and another instantaneous

Comment: @AleksejsFomins how did you implement the other model given that $x$ is hidden?

Comment: The point is to infer the hidden variables $x$ from observations $y$. The variables form a closed system, given a prior for $x_0$, $\alpha$ and the noise model. In case the observable is obtained by means of a function of the hidden variable, not just the noise, the model is called Dynamical Causal Model, however it is only popular in neuroscience community. I was wondering if I can find analogues of this model in regular statistical literature.

Comment: Also, could you suggest a good read for learning about different existing time-series statistical models like ARMA.

Comment: @AleksejsFomins the DCM assumes continuous time (I'm a neuroscientist). It has a stochastic variant with neuronal noise as well (Stochastic DCM). Having said that, in DCM $x$ is latent, but indeed partially observable (due to the assumption that it's zero at the onset of sessions).

Comment: @AleksejsFomins You'll end up looking for non-linear autoregressive models, because the DCM is non-linear in observable space (and sometimes non-linear on latent space)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115303/discussion-between-aleksejs-fomins-and-firebug).